# magento theme falling back to default theme evenafter theme is changed in admin side

Tags: magento, themes, magento-1.7

magento theme falling back to default theme evenafter theme is changed in admin side.
I tried clearing all cache and checked 
 System > Configuration > GENERAL > Design > Themes > Layout, it is "blank" and  System > Configuration > GENERAL > Design > Package > Current Package Name is "default".

Answer (score 0):

In System > Configuration > GENERAL > Design > Package > Current Package Name, you put the name of the folder that is directly under app/design/frontend/ that you are going to use for your theme. inside this folder is your theme. if the theme you are using is not 'default' you need to put the name of this folder to System > Configuration > GENERAL > Design > Themes > Default.
eg: if your package name is mypackage and theme name is mytheme you need to put those in current package name and default themes respectively